# Android: Invalid column count(*) in ContentResolver query()

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-context

I am developing an Android application and I want to read the call log. 
I have found tons of ways to do it but I want to use more complex queries such as COUNT, SUM combined with GROUP BY.

The following works:

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, null);
```

If I want to use more advanced syntax, like the following

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
String[] columns = new String[] { CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "count(" + CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + ") as total" };
String selection = " 0 == 0) (GROUP BY (" + CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "), (" + CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME + ")";
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(allCalls, columns, selection, null, "count("+ CallLog.Calls.NUMBER +") DESC");
```

the application crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column count(number) as total
```

I have tried different variants like count(*) as total, count(*) without the "as total", but still nothing.

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I am developing in Android API level 19 (4.4.2)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is crashing because your use of `count(" + CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + ") as total` in the `columns` variable is illegal. You can only put Strings representing column names into that argument to `contentResolver.query()`, such as CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, nothing else. You can retrieve a count by running a query and then getting the count from the cursor returned, but the content provider/resolver model really does not support a group by clause. I've never tried but maybe someone else knows a workaround for that. But your group by clause is being interpreted as part of an SQL where clause. It does support an order by clause so replacing your `query` call with the following may be helpful :

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(allCalls, columns, selection, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "," + CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
```

Comment: The thing is, I have seen a lot of questions and answers here that use GROUP BY in the column name. I will keep on trying. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: And for the second part, you are right, I can get that information from the cursor, but since I found people using aggregate functions I thought it will work.

Comment: You're welcome. Are you sure there were using GROUP BY with a content resolver? You can use that clause directly on an SQLiteDatabase object using a raw query, but with a contentResolver, I don't think so. The thing is data in a content provider may not even be in a database so GROUP BY wouldn't apply. But best of luck finding a solution. I will check back later to see if someone knew of a way to do it.

Comment: I accepted this as a solution. Indeed, you cannot do a GROUP BY in the query() function. It was probably an ugly hack in older versions of Android.